# I want to add my editbox data to a local table?

Tags: android, onclick, smartface.io, editbox

How can I add a data to a local table from editbox. I have done many changes to my code `onButton` click.

**I have added this code**

```
Data.execute("insert into Sample_Table values('Name')",Pages.Page1.EditBox1.text);
alert(Pages.Page1.EditBox1.text);
```

But my data is not added in **Sample_Table**.
How can I add data to it if anybody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a  very helpful document about dataset queries, you should check it : 
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/data-network/sql-query-execution/

Try the code below :

```
var myEditbox = new SMF.UI.EditBox({
        left : "10%",
        top : "20%",
        text : ""
    });
var myButton1 = new SMF.UI.TextButton({
        left : "10%",
        top : "40%",
        text : "create insert",
        onPressed : function (e) {
            Data.execute("Create table Sample_Table (col1 int)");
            Data.execute("insert into Sample_Table (col1) values(?)", myEditbox.text);
        }
    });
var myButton2 = new SMF.UI.TextButton({
        left : "10%",
        top : "60%",
        text : "value",
        onPressed : function (e) {
            var myValue = Data.execute('select col1 from Sample_Table where rowId = 1');
            alert(myValue);
        }
    });
```

Add these 3 objects to your page, it will work.